# What does the given symbol symbolize

Tags: notation

$$10y-10y=40-40$$
I didn't know what it meant so I searched it on Microsoft math
The answer was given as
$$y\in\mathbb R$$
What does it mean

Comment: It means that each $y \in \mathbb R$ satisfies the equation $10y-10y=40-40.$

Comment: The symbol $\in$ is the stardard binary operator for being an element of some set. Specifically, $a\in X$ means that $a$ is an element of the set $X$. If $X$ is a set defined by a predicate $P(x)$ in one variable (in the sense of $X$ being a set such that, for all $x$, $x\in X$ if and only if $P(x)$ is true), then $a\in X$ means that $P(a)$ is true.

Comment: The equation can be simplified to "$0=0$" hence it holds for every real number $y$.

Comment: $y\in\mathbb{R}$ simply means that $y$ is in the set $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $y$ is a real number.

Comment: $y$ can also be a variable, often also denoted by $x$. For example, solve the equation $10y-10=40x-40$.